# Visual studio code automatically change folder tree when navigate code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any setting for automatically changing the folder tree of visual studio code when navigate code? Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about "explorer.autoReveal": true;  so that when you focus an editor that file is highlighted in the explorer, even if its parent folders were closed?  True is the default already.

Comment: Even if "explorer.autoReveal": true, the explorer does not automatically change when navigating code.

Comment: What do you mean by "navigating code"?

Comment: "Go to Definition" menu. I hope when I go to definition of method, the folder tree could change accordingly.

Comment: And how do you want the folder tree to change - beyond indicating which file you went to after "Go to Definition"?

Comment: I want the sidebar to reveal the file tree and focus on the specific file which I am working on. It looks like that this is a bug, and someone had file the issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/68627